# Read file path from Input Stream

Tags: file, java-8, path, inputstream

It seems very easy question, but I am didn't found any definite solution.
I am trying to read file path from `InputStream` object,

```
 InputStream screenshotPathStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/" + "screenshotPath");
```

I tried to used :

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(screenshotPathStream));
            String screenshotPath = reader.readLine();
```

but getting `null` on `reader.readLine()`
, I want to retrieve highlighted path mark in below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: The purpose of a `Reader` is to read the *content* of the file. How did you come to the idea that this could give you the path? Are you randomly trying everything that will return a `String`?

Comment: @Holger this snippet I took from different application, there it is used to fetch path from `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)` . But Now, I am randomly trying everything to make it work.

Comment: 1) You can use `getResource(…)` in the first place to get a `URL`. But there is no guarantee that a resource resolves to a `file:` URL. In fact, for deployed applications, it is rather unusual to be a file. Rather, it will be a zip/jar entry or be stored in a module image. 2) Likewise, when you have an `InputStream`, there is no guarantee that it is a `FileInputStream` and even if it is a `FileInputStream`, there is no guaranty that it remembers its path. What you discovered in the debugger, is an implementation detail. There is no API to ask for that path.

Comment: I already tried with `URL`, but it was giving completely different path. Hope there might be any api in apache

Comment: Apparently your resource is not a file, but the `InputStream` has been constructed around a temporarily extracted file. That’s just one more reason not to mess around with implementation details. Whatever you want to do with this file might not work anyway. Perhaps just another instance of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/242352).